# CSS : z-index/stacking issue

Tags: html, css, position, z-index

I've been working on a new version of my website, and to make it cleaner I installed a jQuery Dropdown menu, so the navigation looks cleaner.

The thing is, the links appear underneath the following content div, and I'm not sure how I can fix this.. I've looked into the z-index property, and I tried setting the position and z-index of both divs, but to no avail, they stay improperly stacked.

Here's the link of the page, so you can see what I mean :
http://minecrafteurope.com/?theme=compositio

Any idea on how I can fix this ?

Thanks !
Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `overflow: hidden;` from `.menu`

Comment: And that solved it, thank you very much ! Can't believe I didn't think of overflow !